# How to parse multiple expressions when using the rply library

Tags: python, parsing

I created a parser using the rply library for python and can currently perform basic arithmetic. The problem is that I cannot parse more than one line when reading from a file. 
Say I have:
5 + 4 on a single line.

That parses with no errors. But if I have something like the following over two lines.

5 + 4

7 * 3

I get this error: rply.errors.ParsingError.

I have set my lexer to ignore newlines and spaces:

```
lg.ignore('\n')
lg.ignore('\s+')
```

And these are my productions:

```
@pg.production('main : expression')
def main(p):
    return p[0]

@pg.production(’expression : NUMBER’)
def expression_number(p):
    return Number(int(p[0].getstr()))

@pg.production(’expression : expression PLUS expression’)
def expression_binop(p):
left = p[0]
right = p[2]
if p[1].gettokentype() == ’AND’:
    return Add(left, right)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this is your actual code? You should not be using `’smart quotes’` in your source.

Comment: I copied and pasted the code from a pdf as it matched my actual code.

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: I am unable to parse multiple expressions within the same file.

Comment: have you tried stripping the lines?

Comment: Yes, I have. It doesn't work. The lexer handles the removal of '\n'.

Comment: Post all your code to pastebin.

Comment: My code is basically same as the one here: https://github.com/alex/rply/blob/master/README.rst  . I added: lg.ignore('\n') and a basic function to read from a file.

Answer (score 1):

This will work, you had no multiplication setup:

```
from rply import ParserGenerator, LexerGenerator
from rply.token import BaseBox

lg = LexerGenerator()
# Add takes a rule name, and a regular expression that defines the rule.
lg.add("PLUS", r"\+")
lg.add("MINUS", r"-")
lg.add("NUMBER", r"\d+")
lg.add('MUL', r'\*') # added MUL here

lg.ignore(r"\s+")

# This is a list of the token names. precedence is an optional list of
# tuples which specifies order of operation for avoiding ambiguity.
# precedence must be one of "left", "right", "nonassoc".
# cache_id is an optional string which specifies an ID to use for
# caching. It should *always* be safe to use caching,
# RPly will automatically detect when your grammar is
# changed and refresh the cache for you.
pg = ParserGenerator(["NUMBER", "PLUS", "MINUS",'MUL'], # added MUL here
        precedence=[("left", ['PLUS', 'MINUS'])], cache_id="myparser")

@pg.production("main : expr")
def main(p):
    # p is a list, of each of the pieces on the right hand side of the
    # grammar rule
    return p[0]
@pg.production("expr : expr MUL expr") # added MUL here
@pg.production("expr : expr PLUS expr")
@pg.production("expr : expr MINUS expr")
def expr_op(p):
    lhs = p[0].getint()
    rhs = p[2].getint()
    if p[1].gettokentype() == "PLUS":
        return BoxInt(lhs + rhs)
    elif p[1].gettokentype() == "MINUS":
        return BoxInt(lhs - rhs)
    elif p[1].gettokentype() == 'MUL': # added Mul here
        return BoxInt(lhs * rhs)
    else:
        raise AssertionError("This is impossible, abort the time machine!")

@pg.production("expr : NUMBER")
def expr_num(p):
    return BoxInt(int(p[0].getstr()))

lexer = lg.build()
parser = pg.build()

class BoxInt(BaseBox):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def getint(self):
        return self.value
with open("hello.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            print parser.parse(lexer.lex(line)).value
21
9
```

Comment: The multiplication was just an example. Even if I parse two consecutive addition statements from a file, it doesn't work. The problem is parsing several statements from a file, not just a single statement per time.

Comment: It is working perfectly for me reading from a file.i will add how i am using it when i get back on my computer

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, have you got back yet? :) It's been 10 years but people have been encountering this problem. I ended up with just reading my file line by line passing all the same state in there... It looks as crutches though.